# Noscript button missing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, noscript

Windows XP professional SP3
Firefox 13.0.1
NoScript Addon 2.4.6

I can't click Javascript links, like for opening a popup window (which I usually don't care about, but this time it was Important :-( ). I mention NoScript as I used to have a button where I could temporarily enable Javascript so the link would work, but with one of the latest updates this seems to be gone.
I have "Block popup windows" unchecked and "Enable Javascript" checked in Options.

How can I get the NoScript button back?

Comment: Do you have the add-ons bar enable?

Comment: Press alt and the Tools menu will appear, the add-ons bar option will be in the View option/Toolbars

Comment: @Nam - Toolbar is visible at the bottom, but only shows Linkification button.

Comment: Then you should check the no-script add-ons my no-script is always shown in the add-ons toolbar. Might be something else block your scripts.

Comment: @Nam - I'm not sure about that. The add-ons manager says NoScript is enabled, so I presume it will be that that blocks the scripts. It's just not visible. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Thanks for your reactions anyway.

Comment: Check this: http://noscript.net/faq#qa3_2 (I cannot find the NoScript toolbar button. Where is it?)

Comment: @lupincho - I tried that, but the NoScript button didn't show in the collection to choose from. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had tried by re-installing FF, but I didn't want to remove my personal settings, so I kept those. I didn't expect they would cause the problems I had.

But being fed up with them, I just did a complete uninstall, including personal settings (that hurt!), and re-installed. Also re-installed all add-ons, and they now seem to work properly.

So, the NoScript button is where it should be, and also Googlebar and Tab Mix Plus work again (which they didn't, even after re-installing). I presume something must have happened which corrupted personal settings, and which persisted through reconfigurations.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Go to any website that uses Javascript so Noscript blocks it and notifies you at the bottom of the screen. Click on Options in the notification, go to the appearance tab and check the "Show status bar label" box. Voilá!